# get an empty array when using tie::file in perl

Tags: perl, file, tie

I tried to use Tie::File in perl to access files by writing a small piece of code. However, the "T_array" I got by running the code below seems to be empty:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w 
use strict;
use warnings;
use Tie::File;


my @T_array;
my $input3_file_name="/test/QtermsSorted.txt";##"newQurls";
tie @T_array, 'Tie::File', $input3_file_name|| die "Could not open $input3_file_name\n";
my $len=scalar(@T_array);
print "$len\n";
##print "$T_array[0]";
##untie @T_array;
```

The out put of it is 0, which means the array is empty. The "QtermsSorted.txt" is generated by perl under Linux. First, I though it might be the file coding issue and I tried to use "iconv -t utf8 QtermsSorted.txt" to change the coding, but it did not work. However, when I used a txt file created in Windows 8, the out put size was correct. I wonder whether you may tell me what is wrong and how to fix it. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: Always use `or die ...`

One thing I see is that your `|| die ...` won't ever fire. It is a precedence problem. What gets executed is

```
tie @T_array, 'Tie::File', ($input3_file_name|| die "Could not open $input3_file_name\n");
```

and what you mean is

```
tie( @T_array, 'Tie::File', $input3_file_name )|| die "Could not open $input3_file_name\n";
```

if you change from `||` or `or` you will get the result you mean. Also you should add `$!` to the error string, so that you can see the error.

```
tie @T_array, 'Tie::File', $input3_file_name or die "Could not open $input3_file_name: $!\n";
```

Hopefully then you will get some reason as to why the tie is failing.

Comment: Adding `$!` to the `die` message would probably give that reason.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But when I changed the code as you suggested, the file could not be open. I used   "open(inputfile,$input3_file_name)" which worked, whereas the "tie" method did not work. The QtermsSorted.txt file I want to open is relatively big: "53M". Is that the reason why I cannot open it? Thanks.

Comment: @KuangLu, I edited the last code example after TLP's correct comment. Please try this to see the error.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found the problem is that I do not have write access to the file.

Comment: Ah! I'm glad you figured it out!